# How to read xml-file using XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root lev="0">
        content of root
        <child1 lev="1" xmlns="root">
            content of child1
        </child1>
    </root>
```

and next code:

```
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("D:\\test.xml");

        foreach (var node in xml.Descendants())
        {
            if (node is XElement)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(node.Value);
                //some code...
            }
        }
```

I get messages:

> content of rootcontent of child1
>
> content of child1

But I need to the messages:

> content of root
>
> content of child1

How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to XML - Get given XElement's text content without child elements' text content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302158/linq-to-xml-get-given-xelements-text-content-without-child-elements-text-con)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got needed result by the code:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("D:\\test.xml");

foreach (var node in xml.DescendantNodes())
{
    if (node is XText)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((XText)node).Value);
        //some code...
    }
    if (node is XElement)
    {
        //some code for XElement...
    }
}
```

Thank for attention!

Answer (score 3):

The string value of an element is all of the text that is within it (including inside child elements.

If you want to get the value of every non-empty text node:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("D:\\test.xml");

foreach (var node in xml.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>())
{
    var value = node.Value.Trim();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value);
        //some code...
    }
}
```

Comment: @SQLprog You haven't made it clear what you're actually trying to do, so I'm not sure what to suggest beyond this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `foreach(XElement node in xdoc.Nodes())` instead.