# loading xml in c# but incomplete

Tags: c#, winforms

As in my last post I now managed to load the xml file in c# with the following code. But it is not loaded correctly as you can see in the picture below. Thank you in advance! :)

[image: code for xml loading in c#]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        XmlReader xmlFile;
        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(@"test.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I dislike pictures in questions but, I dislike links to pictures presented as code even more.

Comment: Most likely you have more than one table.  The Readxml() only can successfully read an xml file with no attributes that contains no more than 4 layers.  After that the DataSet contains fragmented tables that cannot be recombined and is unusable.  I usually use Xml Linq to parse file and put data into tables that are well organized.

Comment: So you would prefer using Xml Linq. Are there already existing examples for code? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42154603